# How do i set an onClickListener on a view that gets animated?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a simple bubble popping app, bubbles floating from the bottom of the screen to the top. I would like users to be able to tap on those bubbles and for it to make a sound. I already incorporated sound into my app and set the `onClickListeners()` but when I click the bubble images it does not make a sound. I understand that this is due to the image position being adjusted when the animation method is called.

I have found some answers online, but most of it is too complicated for me to implement as I'm new at this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView bubble, bubble1, bubble2, bubble3, bubble4, bubble5, bubble6, bubble7, bubble8;

    //Created an array that stores the images
    private ImageView[] IMGS= new ImageView[9];
    private SoundPlayer sound;


    private int deviceHeight;

    private Animation mAnimation;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sound = new SoundPlayer(this);


        //linked up views
        bubble = findViewById(R.id.bubble);
        bubble1 = findViewById(R.id.bubble1);
        bubble2 = findViewById(R.id.bubble2);
        bubble3 = findViewById(R.id.bubble3);
        bubble4 = findViewById(R.id.bubble4);
        bubble5 = findViewById(R.id.bubble5);
        bubble6 = findViewById(R.id.bubble6);
        bubble7 = findViewById(R.id.bubble7);
        bubble8 = findViewById(R.id.bubble8);

        //assigned the array to the imageviews
        IMGS[0] = bubble;
        IMGS[1] = bubble1;
        IMGS[2] = bubble2;
        IMGS[3] = bubble3;
        IMGS[4] = bubble4;
        IMGS[5] = bubble5;
        IMGS[6] = bubble6;
        IMGS[7] = bubble7;
        IMGS[8] = bubble8;

        getDeviceHeight();
        animateBubble();
    }





    public void animateBubble(){
        //looped thru the array of Imageviews and animated the images stored in it.

        for (ImageView img : IMGS) {
            mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -deviceHeight);
            mAnimation.setDuration(4000);
            mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
            bubble.setAnimation(mAnimation);
            bubble.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            img.setAnimation(mAnimation);
            img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    sound.playPopSound();


                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {



                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
            }


    }


    public void getDeviceHeight(){
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        deviceHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    }


    public void playSound(View view) {
        sound.playPopSound();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use TranslateAnimation, it is an old way of animating Views (that should probably be deprecated). That type of animation doesn't actually move the View but only the drawing of the View, which is why clicks on the current visible position of your bubbles won't work.

Instead, you can use the animation API introduced in API 14. More details here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reposition-view

A simplified version of your animation could be written like that:

```
img.animate().translationY(-deviceHeight).setDuration(4000).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer said, you are using value animator which only animates the coordinates value of the graphic. You should use ObjectAnimation where all of its properties moves with the view. For your case to play pop sound on start you can use

```
img.animate().translationY(-deviceHeight).setDuration(4000).withStartAction(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sound.playPopSound();
                }
            });
```